# Trace API get block call fails on a few blocks - _binary_to_variant function crashing

Tags: nodeos, api, plugin

I'm running 6 mainnet archive nodes, today morning onwards a few blocks are returning 500, internal server error!

```
curl --location $url/v1/trace_api/get_block --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"block_num": "356339452" }' | jq .

{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Service Error",
  "error": {
    "code": 3015013,
    "name": "unpack_exception",
    "what": "Unpack data exception",
    "details": [
      {
        "message": "Stream unexpectedly ended; unable to unpack field 'to' of struct 'transfer'",
        "file": "abi_serializer.cpp",
        "line_number": 374,
        "method": "_binary_to_variant"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The nodes are running v4.0.5.

I tried rewinding the node back using

```
nodeos --genesis.json /root/local/genesis.json --data-dir /data --config-dir /root/local \
--hard-replay-blockchain --terminate-at-block 356339451
```

But afterwards it complained about database version mismatch.

```
warn  2024-02-08T11:54:53.441 nodeos    chain_plugin.cpp:1077         plugin_initialize    ] 3060005 bad_database_version_exception: Database is an unknown or unsupported version
state database version pre-dates versioning, please restore from a compatible snapshot or replay!
    {}
    nodeos  controller.cpp:687 validate_db_version

error 2024-02-08T11:54:53.472 nodeos    main.cpp:161                  main                 ] 3060005 bad_database_version_exception: Database is an unknown or unsupported version
state database version pre-dates versioning, please restore from a compatible snapshot or replay!
    {}
    nodeos  controller.cpp:687 validate_db_version
rethrow
    {}
    nodeos  chain_plugin.cpp:1077 plugin_initialize
```

So I tried syncing from a recent snapshot `snapshot-2024-02-08-04-eos-v6-0356339018.bin`

Even then this block was returning with the same response.

There are a few more blocks with the same error in the next 10k range!

```
356339452
356339534
356340111
356340363
356340822
```

Is this network wide issue, or only for me, how to recover?

Only thing left to do is to upgrade to `v5.0.0` which I'm currently trying.

Update: the upgrade also didn't help.